# What is the product topology on this set?

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y=\{0,1\}$ and let $T$ be the discrete topology on $Y$. Consider the product topology $T'$ on $ X = \Pi_{n\in\mathbf{N}} \{0,1\}$.

Is $T'$ the discrete topology on $X$? How does a set in the product topology look like?

How do I go about investigating what $T'$ is? I know $T = \{\emptyset,\{0\}, \{1\}. Y\}$

Comment: $T'$ is infinite and compact (by the Tychonoff's theorem) and thus not discrete. A bit counterintuitive but $(X,T')$ is homeomorphic to [the Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Comment: What do open sets in the product topology look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general fact.

Given a non-empty discrete space $X$, we have that $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is metrizable. Indeed, one can check that the product topology on $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is induced by the metric

$$d(f,g) = \begin{cases}0 \quad\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  f =g \\ 2^{-\min\{n: f(n) \neq g(n)\}} \quad f \neq g\end{cases}$$